# Jquery check for duplicate dropdown values

Tags: jquery, drop-down-menu

I'm trying to do prevent a user from having the same value in two drop down menus. Jquery is returning true regardless of the values selected.

```
$("select[id$='go']").change(function() {
    var value = $(this);
    $("select[id$='go']").each(function() {
        if ($(this).val() === value.val()) {
            $('#work').html("DUBS");
        }
    });
});

<select id="_go">
    <option value="1">1</option>
    <option value="2">2</option>
    <option value="3">3</option>
</select>

<select id="_gogo">
    <option value="1">1</option>
    <option value="2">2</option>
    <option value="3">3</option>
</select>

<div id="work"></div>
```

http://jsfiddle.net/zbaKE/1/

Is there a proper way to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to remove the DUBS text on `false`, and also not test the same select field. Use `not()` to achieve this.

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/zbaKE/3/

```
$("select[id$='go']").change(function() {
   var value = $(this).val();
   $("select[id$='go']").not(this).each(function() {
       if ($(this).val() == value) {
           $('#work').html("DUBS");
       }else{
           $("#work").html("SUBS");
       }
   });
});​
```

Answer (score 3):

If you want to prevent user to select same value from other dropdown, you may use something like this;

```
var $select = $("select[id$='go']");
$select.change(function() {
    $select
      .not(this)
      .find('option')
      .prop('disabled', '')
      .filter('[value='+this.value+']')
      .prop('disabled','disabled');
});
$select.eq(0).trigger('change');
```

working case is [here](http://jsfiddle.net/karalamalar/zbaKE/5/) ([`.not()`](http://api.jquery.com/not), [`.find()`](http://api.jquery.com/find), [`.prop()`](http://api.jquery.com/prop), [`.filter()`](http://api.jquery.com/filter))

Comment: Though a bit off from my original direction, this is very helpful. +1

Answer (score 0):

I don't think it's returning `true` every time, your logic just doesn't remove the `DUBS` text if `false`.

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/zbaKE/2/

```
$("select[id$='go']").change(function() {
    var value = $(this);
    $("select[id$='go']").each(function() {
        if ($(this).val() === value.val()) {
            $('#work').html("DUBS");
        } else {
            $('#work').html("");
        }
    });
});​
```

Answer (score 0):

The DUBS text isn't set back to empty before each change

Your jQuery could be written simply like this

```
$("select[id$='go']").change(function(){
    $('#work').html('Different');
    if ($("select[id=_go]").val() == $("select[id=_gogo]").val()){
        $('#work').html("Same");
    }
});
```

Here is a working example: http://jsfiddle.net/tuC4Y/1/

Comment: The change code was already attached to both dropdowns, using $= in the attribute selector. The .each function would be needed if there was another select - so it could just be a limitation of the example.

Comment: @Tim Your method is the manual way to do it. Suppose in my work I have 10 dropdown menus. I'm seeking a way to evaluate each `select` by iteration, not by checking each individual select id.

Comment: @Norse Yep sorry, guess I took the "in two drop down menus" too literally