# Code works fine in JSFiddle but not in my browser

Tags: javascript, jquery, dropdown

I'm working on multiple dropdown menus to be used for ranking. I found this excellent code from stackoverflow:

[How to prevent duplicate values in multiple dropdowns using jQuery](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27075606/how-to-prevent-duplicate-values-in-multiple-dropdowns-using-jquery)

It works nicely on JSFiddle, but I can't seem to get the code to work offline in my Chrome or IE browser. Can someone help?

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function() {
        $(".go").change(function() {
            var selVal = [];
            $(".go").each(function() {
                selVal.push(this.value);
            });

            $(this).siblings(".go").find("option").removeAttr("disabled").filter(function() {
                var a = $(this).parent("select").val();
                return (($.inArray(this.value, selVal) > -1) && (this.value != a))
            }).attr("disabled", "disabled");
        });
        $(".go").eq(0).trigger('change');
    });
</script>
```

Comment: Did you add jQuery, https://learn.jquery.com/about-jquery/how-jquery-works/

Comment: Hi there,

Yes, on all of my landing pages, I have a <script> tag with the source path to jquery.js (v1.11.0).

Comment: What exactly do you mean by "doesn't work"? Does it do anything at all? Do you get any error messages in the console? Does your HTML code match what the JS code is expecting? Do you have anything else on your page that might be affecting it?

Comment: Can you add the link to a live demo hosted on a public domain?

Answer (score -1):

It depends on what "doesn't work" means for you. :) Can you see any errors on your console? Can you see all the 5 selects? Did you copy correctly the codes? The JSFiddle code works perfectly for me with 2.1.4 jQuery.

Comment: Sorry, I should've been more specific.

When I tested it offline in Chrome and IE by selecting, say, Option #1 in the first dropdown, that option is NOT grayed out/disabled in the other dropdowns.