# Populate multiple drop down from database in php

Tags: php, mysql, database, drop-down-menu

I have multiple drop downs which are being populated from database but I want something like this.........

1. Every drop down have same options
2. If I select one option in any drop down then that option would not be visible in any drop down, but if I deselect it then it would be visible in all drop downs.

I found something that is somewhere helpful But I need this in table row

[How to prevent duplicate values in multiple dropdowns using jQuery](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27075606/how-to-prevent-duplicate-values-in-multiple-dropdowns-using-jquery/27077009)

Please look it and suggest me any Solution.

Thanks in advance

Comment: What's your problem exactly ? What have you tried ? You probably have to use some JavaScript to show/hide options in your menus

Comment: I have 21 names which are being populated in 21 drop down list using database dynamically because names can change, now I want to take response with UNIQUE selected drop down

Answer (score 0):

This has to be done using AJAX https://www.w3schools.com/php/php_ajax_database.asp

When a dropdown value is change an Ajax script should be called which will update the other drop down lists.

Hope this helps. Its not tricky at all you just have to understand the concept.

Comment: how about you post that code in a new question. As your question is too open and no-one can really help you.